# How to fix \pex label numbers inside tabularx?

Tags: numbering, tabularx, linguistics, expex

`expex`'s `\tl` command for placing labels inside tables seems to be incompatible with `tabularx`, with the label numbers starting at a higher number with every `\tl` placed.

Is there an easy way to patch this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expex,tabularx}
\labels

\begin{document}
    Regular \verb|tabular|s have proper label numbering, starting at a. in each \verb|\pex|
    
    \pex
        \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabular}
    \xe
    \pex~
        \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabular}
    \xe
    
    But \verb|tabularx|s start at a different number depending on how many \verb|\tl|s are set
    
    \pex
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
    \pex~
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
                & text \\
                & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
    \pex~
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
                & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
    
    And at even higher numbers if you use \verb|\ex| instead
    
    \ex
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**

I just thought of a quick-fix by resetting `\pexcnt` before every first label.
But I am still looking for a more global solution if possible.

```
\newcommand{\tlx}{\pexcnt=97\tl}
```

...

```
\pex
    \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
        \tlx & text \\
        \tl  & text \\
        \tl  & text
    \end{tabularx}
\xe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularx` preserves latex counters declared with `\setcounter` but not plain tex style allocations with `\newcount`, you can make a latex name shadow the existing allocation

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expex,tabularx}
\labels
\makeatletter
\let\c@excnt\excnt
\let\c@pexcnt\pexcnt
\@addtoreset{excnt}{@ckpt}
\@addtoreset{pexcnt}{@ckpt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Regular \verb|tabular|s have proper label numbering, starting at a. in each \verb|\pex|
    
    \pex
        \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabular}
    \xe
    \pex~
        \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabular}
    \xe
    
    But \verb|tabularx|s start at a different number depending on how many \verb|\tl|s are set
    
    \pex
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
    \pex~
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
                & text \\
                & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
    \pex~
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
                & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
    
    And at even higher numbers if you use \verb|\ex| instead
    
    \ex
        \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}[t]{cX}
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text \\
            \tl & text
        \end{tabularx}
    \xe
\end{document}
```

I assume the final c,d,e labels are right (I get the same with `tabular`) but I don't know this package.

Comment: Thank you! The final labels are not right, but ``\tl`` isn't set up to work with ``\ex`` anyways. I just included what I noticed while experimenting, but thinking about it again now, it was to be expected, since ``\ex`` doesn't reset ``\pexcnt``.